# WMSVC Certificate stored in Web Hosting not Personal

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2019

I know I have been through this before, but for the life of me cannot remember how I managed to overcome it - perhaps purchased a new certificate.

Recently updated the SSL cert and by default it was stored in 'Web Hosting' - after running a PCI scan it failed for out of date cert. Confused for a while then spotted WMSVC port.

Stopped WMSVC and clicked on the drop-down for certificates. Only those in the personal store are showing. How do I bind a valid certificate to this port that is in the Web Hosting store?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite easy as it happens.

Open MMC as administrator

File > Add/Remove Snap In

Certificates > Add [OK]

Computer Account [Next]

Local Computer [Finish]

Selected Snap-Ins > Console Root > Certificates (Local) [OK]

Console Root > Certificates > Web Hosting

Highlight certificate and copy - paste into Personal

Now the certificate is available in the WMSVC drop down for selection

Comment: Another way is to use `netsh` or other tools to manipulate Windows HTTP API certificate mappings, but clearly using GUI is easier for most people.